# Schema based multitenancy with maria DB, JPA and spring boot 1.5.4

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, mariadb

I have implemented schema based multi-tenancy with single connection pool using :
Spring Boot 1.5.4, Spring Data Source, MariaDB, JPA

I have included following files for multi-tenancy: 
`CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` -- To identify current tenant
`MultiTenantConnectionProvider` -- To switch schema and release connection
`TenantInterceptor` -- interceptor
`TenantContext` -- Thread local context
application properties -- datasource properties

In case of MYSQL(used mysql driver and dialect):
My code is working fine if I use MySQL data base. I am able to connect to right tenant every time.

In case of MariaDB(used maria DB driver and dialect):
when I make call to server first time, I am getting data from right tenant(T1). After that if I change my tenant(T2) and make server call, I am getting data for first tenant(T1), which is wrong.
I got a work around for this issue. If I skip `connecion.close` in `MultiTenantConnectionProvider.java`, code will work fine. But skipping `connection.close` is not the good approach and it will not work in production.

Please provide some input, Why same code is working fine with MySql but not with Maria DB ???

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Updated mariadb driver to version 2.0.3

```
<properties> 
    <hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version> 
    <mariadb.version>2.0.3</mariadb.version>
</properties>
```